# Text not appearing on screen

Tags: android, html, css, text

I am making an app for phones with html where I want only the center to scroll. So, to test it, I put the word hello in there a bunch. Now I can't find the text I inserted.

(Please don't point out all my other mistakes, I know those are there, and I'm doing that later)

(Also, it probably looks terrible on a computer because of my use of `px` as a measurement. I'd recommend using a mobile compiler like Dcoder)

**CSS**

```
    body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.head {
    background-color: #555555;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 102.3%;
    height: 60px;
    align: center;
    left: -8px;
    top: -9px;
    position: fixed;
}
.main_user_name {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    position: fixed;
    top: -26px;
    left: 55px;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.lower_auto_name {
    color: #ffffff;     
    position: fixed;
    left: 55px;
}
.back {
    margin: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    top: 7px;
    position: fixed;
}
.user_settings {
    color: ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: -160px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: none;
}
.foot {
    background-color: #555555;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 415px;
    height: 50px;
    align: center;
    left: -55px;
    top: 508px;
    position: fixed;
}
.enter_message {
    color: #777777;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 452px;
    left: -30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.modal1 {
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
   display: none;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: #555555;
   left: 0px;
   top: 380px;
   color: #ff0707;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0px;
}
.modal2 {
   height: 60px;
   font-size: 20px;
   display: none;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: #555555;
   left: 0px;
   top: 440px;
   color: #ff0707;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0px;
}
.modal3 {
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
   display: none;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: #555555;
   left: 0px;
   top: 499px;
   color: #ffffff;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0px;
}
.everything {
    top: 60px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="head"><a href="main_screen.html">
<img src="/storage/emulated/0/pictures/eraser/back.png" class="back">
</div></a>
<div class="main_user_name">
<h3><b>Mom</b></h3>
</div>
<div class="lower_auto_name">
<h5>#113A675_76G</h5
</div>
<div class="foot">
</div>
<div class="enter_message">
<h3>Enter Message</h3>
</div>
<div class="user_settings"
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block';document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'">●<br>●<br>●</button>
</div>
<div id="id01" class="modal1">
Block User
</div>
<div id="id02" class="modal2">
Delete All Messages
</div>
<div id="id03" class="modal3" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none';document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none'"">
Cancel    
</div>
</div>
<div class="everything">
<p>
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
hellohellohellohellohellohellohello
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There are quite a few issues with your HTML. Some missing angle brackets and an extra quote here and there. This could easily be your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below css, you should be able to see hello red in color, You have other issues but as you said you will be fixing those.

```
.everything {
   color:red;
    top: 60px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```